# How can LINQ return 0 in place of NULL when being used in Sum?

Tags: vb.net, linq, null, sum

I'm running into an issue with my code when using nested Sum functions. The latest version that fails to account for NULL values is here:

```
TotalHours = Tickets.Sum(Function(x) If(x Is Nothing, 0, x.Ticket_Times.Sum(Function(y) If(y Is Nothing, 0, y.Hours))))
```

I've attempted this with CType as well with the same results:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Decimal which is a non-nullable value type.'
```

TotalHours is a Double, however Hours in the database is a Decimal, so maybe that is what is causing the issue?

Comment: See the remarks section of [`Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Nullable<Double>>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Sum__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Nullable_System_Double___).

Comment: Are you saying that `Hours` is type `Decimal?`, i.e. `Nullable(Of Decimal)`?  In that case, you could replace `y.Hours` with `If(y.Hours.HasValue, y.Hours.Value, 0)`.  You may be also be able to use a null-coalescing operator like this but I'm not sure and haven't tested in this case: `If(y.Hours, 0)`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney If `Nullable(Of T)` then you can also use `GetValueOrDefault`.

Comment: @Craig, I wasn't actually aware of that. Good info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help in the comments I believe I have working code.

```
TotalHours = If(Tickets.Sum(Function(x) x.Ticket_Times.Sum(Function(y) If(CType(y.Hours, Decimal?) Is Nothing, 0, CType(y.Hours, Decimal?)))), 0)
```